# Batch run mogrify including subdirectories

Tags: linux, command-line, find, exec

The command `mogrify -format jpg *.NEF` when run in a directory converts all ***.NEF** files to JPEGs. What I want to do is to be able to run mogrify in ***.NEF** files inside subdirectories as well using one command. I am trying to run something like:

```
find . -type d exec mogrify -format jpg *.NEF \;
```

and of course it is not working. Can someone suggest the proper command?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It looks like mogrify from ImageMagick 6.9.9.19 writes the result in the same directory as the input file, so you can use this command:

```
find . -name '*.NEF' -exec mogrify -format jpg {} +
```

Explanation:

- `-name '*.NEF'` finds all ***.NEF** files; use `-iname` if you want the search to be
  case insensitive.
- `-exec ... {} +` executes the command on all the matching files.
  An alternative would be to combine **find** with **xargs**.

Comment: Just a tip, you may want to expand on this a little as it was marked as low quality. Consider explaining what the command does in detail.

Comment: Working perfect. I use this for convert svg to png with: "find . -name '*.svg' -exec mogrify -format jpg {} +"